# How does a high-speed atomic force microscope (HS-AFM) form a realtime image?

Tags: signal-processing, microscopy, nanoscience

Regular low speed AFM uses tapping to image a surface. How does a high-speed AFM (HS-AFM) capable of imaging a whole area in "real time"? ([Ando et al.](http://www.s.kanazawa-u.ac.jp/phys/biophys/), [ref](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.progsurf.2008.09.001)) Is it just improved signal processing?

Comment: I'm not much of an experimentalist, but I wonder that this might be an awfully broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single element that makes the difference. To build such a racing car, they have improved almost every aspect of standard AFMs. From Ando et al. *High-Speed AFM and Applications to Biomolecular Systems*,  Annu. Rev. Biophys. 2013. 42:393–414 ([link](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-biophys-083012-130324)):

> HS-AFM is materialized by the achievement of three conditions to meet high-speed and low- invasive performance: (a) extensive reduction of time delays in the response of all devices contained
>   in the feedback loop [...], (b) damping of mechanical vibrations caused by fast displacement of the scanner [...], and (c) feedback control technique that can eliminate tip parachuting [...]

To make the difference with standard AFMs, if you want to point to one element, I'd consider globally the PID feedback loop (the "real time" measurement and control of the amplitude of the tip), which in fact contains... every component. In a HS-AFM in tapping mode, the loop works at high frequency (>100 kHz). This means (point *a)* above) that all the electronic delays from the detector, the piezo actuators, the various amplifiers etc., have been minimized. The algorithm itself has been also optimized (point c),

> by developing a feedback controller that can automatically change its gain parameters depending on the cantilever oscillation amplitude during imaging; feedback gain is increased at the downhill region of the sample so that parachuting only rarely occurs

(parachuting occurs when the tip looses contact with the surface during the scan, and limits the maximum scan speed)